# Zip file getting downloaded without .zip extension in Chrome through Java

Tags: java, rest, google-chrome, servlets, zip

1. I am trying to download a zip file from a fixed location present in server.
2. In my Rest method , I am just passing the file name from client (browser) . 
   (Please see below code ).
3. In my Rest method I am sending the zip file to the client.
4. The file gets downloaded on the browser without any issue.

My Issue is that the zip file gets downloaded on browser without .zip extension.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/zip/{filePath}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody void downloadZip(@PathVariable("filePath") String filePath, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

  ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
  File downloadFile = new File(filePath);
  FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);
  // get output stream of the response
  OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

  byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) downloadFile.length()];
  int bytesRead = -1;

  // write bytes read from the input stream into the output stream
  while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
  }
  // get MIME type of the file
  String mimeType = context.getMimeType(fullPath);
  if (mimeType == null) {
    // set to binary type if MIME mapping not found
    mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
  }
  System.out.println("MIME type: " + mimeType);

  // set content attributes for the response
  response.setContentType(mimeType);
  response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());

  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
      String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", downloadFile.getName()));
  logger.error("Filename = " + downloadFile.getName());
  inputStream.close();
  outStream.close();
}
```

PS: The file gets downloaded on some machine with ZIP and in some machine without ZIP. I have tested only on chrome (as per client requirement).
I think, there is an issue with the Chrome settings which I need to look upon (just a guess).

Can someone help upon this?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Change the order between setting the response headers and shoving the file down the output stream - after all, the headers need to leave first.

Comment: Tried, but it doesn't works. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Try the mime-type to "application/zip, application/octet-stream"

Comment: Hi Adrian, Thanks for your quick reply. The mime-type is already application/zip. UPDATE: changing the response header sequence fixed the issue. Can you please post same in the Answer , such that , I can accept your answer. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order between setting the response headers and shoving the file down the output stream - after all, the headers need to leave first.

[Edited]

1. *"Why setting HttpServletResponse in starting effects the code."* 
   Well, simple: the client is supposed to receive instructions of what to do with the payload by interpreting the HTTP response headers. If those are not set in the beginning, sending those headers at the end of the transmission comes too late. And this assumes the HttpServletResponse will actually send those headers when invoked with `setHeader`, which is a big assumption - I suspect those headers will not actually be sent *after* calling `response.getOutputStream` - it is unlikely the response will buffer the entire payload to wait for the caller to specify those headers.

Comment: This works great !   Now, I have a question regarding this behavior. 1) Why setting HttpServletResponse in starting effects the code. 2) Why this works on some machine and doesn't work on some machine (old code).

Comment: 2. "Why this works on some machine and doesn't work on some machine (old code). "
I'm not sure I understand the question: what machine are you taking about: different server machines or different client machines processing the download request?

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  Adrian.  By machine, i meant different client processing the download. (sry,  i should've specified that).  Hence,  i came to the conclusion of chrome issue (specific settings change maybe....)

Comment: @krohit Perhaps older browsers which don't process the attachment filename the way they should. Perhaps will help to google about browser specific version on what header should the be provided to display the correct extension. (to be sincere, I don't have any idea: what I suggested is where I'd start to look if I'd really need to solve this problem).